# Process builder won't find my file

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to compile a java program using the `ProcessBuilder` but everytime i see this error being present on the console even though the file is present at that path.

**ERROR**

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac
>   /Users/foo/Desktop/online-compiler/user1455523443383/Main.java":
>   error=2, No such file or directory

```
@Override
    public ProgramResult executeProgram(File program) throws IOException {
        String parent = program.getParentFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
        String[] commands = new String[]{
            "javac "+program.getAbsolutePath(),
//            "cd "+parent,
//            "java -cp  "+parent+" "+PACKAGE_NAME+"."+MAIN_CLASS
        };

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process executorProcess = builder.start();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(executorProcess.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        ProgramResult result = new ProgramResult();
        result.setOutput(sb.toString());

        return result;
    }
```

**Some more information**

Javac is on the path, as running it(without the file) via ProcessBuilder is printing the help options.

OS : MACOSX

> Conclusions from this questions are

1) ProcessBuilder needs every argument to the command as a separate index , like to execute "javac filename.java" you write this

```
new String[] {"javac" , "filename.java"}
```

2) To execute multiple commands you should be using the following trick

```
new String[]{
               "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                "javac "+
                program.getAbsolutePath()+
                " &&" +
                " java -cp " +
                parent +
                " "+ PACKAGE_NAME+"."+MAIN_CLASS,
}
```

**A big thanks to @kucing_terbang for really digging in this problem with me to solve it.**

Comment: Is  `javac` on your path as the Java program knows it?

Comment: Yes, it is on the path because when i run javac using processBuilder it shows the help options

Comment: Can you give full path of `javac` to program and try?

Comment: Ok ill give it a try

Comment: yeah looks like it's not the issue with `javac` path. Actually error code 2 represent  misuse of shell builtins. Is Path of main file is correct ??. Try running `javac /Users/foo/Desktop/online-compiler/user1455523443383/Main.java` manually on commandline. And check `echo $?` is `2`.

Comment: I have already tried this ,it works on the command line. Plus as i am about to start the processbuilder, i first check using the code if the file is present or not and it is present and then also this fails

Comment: If compiler is saying that its not finding the file then trust it. There must be something wrong the way you are giving path. */Users/foo/Desktop/online-compiler/user1455523443383/Main.java*  Look here again. You might find something. Or may be ask someone to have a look at it. (Sometimes that helps)

Comment: Can you check the permissions for that `Main` file. check exit code [definitions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

Comment: Maybe a permission issue? Can the user your task runs on see the directory in question?

Comment: By using the command line i see the following permissions.
drwxr-xr-x, plus programmatically i printed the canRead and canWrite functions output both say : TRUE TRUE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, if you want to put an argument into the `ProcessBuilder`, you should put in into another index of the array.

So, try change the `command` variable into something like this and try again.

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"javac", program.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Comment: Amazing... I skipped the most important aspect of the ProcessBuilder. Thanks

Comment: So to append second command to it , i should use the three index as "&&","java","filename" ? @kucing_terbang

Comment: @cafebabe1991 : well, I haven't tried that before. But, I assume you're right. Basically, you cannot construct the command into single string as the `ProcessBuilder` will think of it as a single program.

Comment: Now when my arguments are these 
<code>
           "javac",
            program.getAbsolutePath(),
            "&&",
           " java",
            "-cp",
            parent,
            parent+"/"+ PACKAGE_NAME+"."+MAIN_CLASS
</code>

javac thinks && is a flag to it and shows me error

Comment: well, `&&` is logical shell operator. So I don't think it would work in this case :D.

Comment: well. how about you do it this way. `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "all your commands in single string");`?

Comment: was trying this only now as my last option :D

Comment: Nope that does not work takes the rest of the commands as a flag to javac

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103467/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-kucing-terbang).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile a Java class, better use `JavaCompiler` acquired from `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`

`JavaCompiler javaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
javaCompiler.run(null, null, null, program.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Will it just compile or can run the program as well ?

Comment: For compilation this is a nice alternative and would be more robust. Thanks for sharing.. +1